# NEO4J Constraint error `ConstraintCreationFailed`

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, unique-constraint

#### Background

I am attempting to set up a constraint on neo4j using the browser.

I have first of all ran the following, to ensure there is no duplicates;

```cypher
MATCH(m:uri), (b:uri)
WHERE m.value = b.value
AND id(m) <> id(b)
RETURN m, b
ORDER BY id(m)
```

For clarity, I also checked the following returned 0;

```cypher
MATCH (b:uri)
WITH b.value AS value, COLLECT(b) AS branches
WHERE SIZE(branches) > 1
RETURN branches
```

#### What I tried

```cypher
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_urivalue IF NOT EXISTS ON (u:uri) ASSERT u.value IS UNIQUE
```

AND

```cypher
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_urivalue ON (u:uri) ASSERT u.value IS UNIQUE
```

#### The Error

> Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintCreationFailed
>
> `Unable to create Constraint( name='constraint_urivalue', type='UNIQUENESS', schema=(:uri {value}) ):`

#### What else

I have managed to create other node/attribute-constraints using the same code as used above.
Also, I have a development environment where this exact "uri constraint" has been implemented without any issue.

Both are running the exact same version of neo4j.

- Is there anyway to see more detail of the error?
- Any queries worth running to re-check my data?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if there is already a similar constraint?

Comment: You can check existing indexes/constraints using `CALL db.indexes();`  Please share the output of this.

Also, share the complete error message, I think there will be additional details about why it failed.

Comment: Hi @RajendraKadam this is all the error that's being displayed - Do you know how to get more detail from the system?
Thanks for the suggestion but I have checked that there are no other constraints on this node at all. I can confirm the system is still allowing duplicates of this kind, but I have cleared them before trying to run the `CREATE CONSTRAINT` command, and checked there are none left with the initial scripts, listed in my question. Thanks

Comment: What’s your Neo4j version?

Comment: v4.2.3 - Community

Comment: I was checking in the enterprise edition. I think they don’t show the details in the community edition.

Comment: Maybe be logs can help. Check these two files debug.log and neo4j.log